# How to trim unwanted newlines/linebreaks from PHP variable?

Tags: php, javascript, newline, line-breaks

I am getting an error while i am registering php variable to html form element through javascript. Like If In my code there is php variable `$edu_notes` and i am assigning this variable's value to a html form element that is

```
<textarea name="1_1_50" id="1_1_50" ></textarea>
```

and My Javascript code is :

```
document.getElementById('1_1_50').value = "<?php echo $edu_notes; ?>";
```

the value of `$edu_notes` comes from linkedin profile which is :

```
"First Text Line

Second Text Line"
```

there is a gap of blank line between its first text line and second text line.
And the javascript gives an error that is

```
unterminated string literal
"First Text line
```

Javascript is not getting the full value as a string because of blank line. I have tried some php functions like `filter_var(),nl2br(),trim()` but not resolving this issue. I have also tried to type cast through `(string)  $edu_notes`.

In my source file what i am getting please see screenshot below :

[image]

I am doing this type of functionality because all the form elements are coming from database dynamicaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('1_1_50').value =
    '<?php echo str_replace("\n", "\\n", $edu_notes) ?>';
```

Comment: @GitsD - Please click the outlined checkmark below the vote tally next to this answer if it is the one you consider your answer.

Comment: i have tried to click on this tick mark from tha starting..but it waits for 7 minuts..thats why delay to tick.sory...

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
  document.getElementById('1_1_50').value =   '<?php echo str_replace(array( "\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d"), "' + \"\\r\\n \"  + '", $edu_notes); ?>'
```

Which will replace any newlines in the string with JS-friendly returns.

Comment: @karel please can u tell me why we use array in this case..??

Comment: @GitsD This way, any type of return will be converted.

Comment: @GitsD - An array of values to search for and be replaced can be provided: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php, so you don't have to do multiple calls.

Comment: Oops.. I had "<? php" instead of "<?php".
FTFY.

Comment: @kerel i have changed a little in your code and its working fine...Thanks you too...cheers

Comment: @kerel it was not an issue with your "<? php". I did not paste your full code instead from str_replace(). So it was a problem with many quotes with javascript concatenation (+) that is confusing. So i removed that and made a simple php.

Comment: Ah.. Well I typed the code in the StackOverflow answer box instead of an IDE to check for syntax so mistakes are easily made.
Anyways, glad it works now.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it needs to be set on the same line.  In PHP, replace the newline character with the literal `\n` and it should work fine.  If it's a single line textbox, replace newline with a space.

```
<?php echo str_replace("\n", " ", $edu_notes); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo str_replace("\n", "\\n", $edu_notes); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the multi-line string construct in javascript.

Eg.

```
  var myStr = "line one \
line two";
```

To re-create this in your php code, replace the new lines with a '\' and a new line :-

```
"First Text Line

Second Text Line"
```

to

```
"First Text Line \

Second Text Line"
```

This can be done in php using preg_replace :-

```
$edu_notes = preg_replace( '#\n#', '\\\n', $edu_notes );
```

Hope this helps.